# How to replace a "\n" and "\t" from a string

Tags: regex, perl

Hi all i am very new to perl.I have a string like `$string = "hi\n how are \t you?";` string itself contains a `"\n"` and `"\t"`.how do i replace them with nothing?

for ex:

```
verfText  = "Verify the following in ESIS-5000 display:\n" 
verfText += " - The Air Data Source submenu is displayed as following from top to bottom:\n"
verfText += "\ta)Submenu Title\n\tb)Standby Source\n\tc)ADS Source\n\td)Back Button\n\n" 
verfText += " - The air data source submenu title with the "  
verfText += "text 'ADS' on line one and 'Source' on line two.\n\n" 
verfText += " - Standby Source(ADS4) validity is valid and the Standby Source menu item is shown as a radio button " 
verfText += "with the label 'STBY' on line one and 'ADS' on line two.\n\n" 
verfText += " - Label 'ADS' on line one and 'Source' on line two in ADS Source momentary submenu button and " 
verfText += "it is displayed in white."
```

I want to replace all the `"\n"` and `"\t"` from the string please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcdsr) operator,

```
$string =~ tr|\n\t||d;
```

Explanation,

`/d` modifier deletes found but unreplaced characters.

---

On the other hand, if you want to replace literal `\n` and `\t` like in

`$string = 'hi\n how are \t you?';`

then you can use regex,

```
$string =~ s|\\[nt]||g;
```

Comment: in which case will a character be found but not replaced ?

Comment: @aelor when it doesn't have corresponding character in replacement list, ie. in `tr|AB|a|`, `B` will not be replaced unlike `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't look like perl.  There are no semicolons and you are using += which is for numbers instead of .= which is for strings.  It should look more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $verfText;

$verfText  = "Verify the following in ESIS-5000 display:\n" ;
$verfText .= " - The Air Data Source submenu is displayed as following from top to bottom:\n";
$verfText .= "\ta)Submenu Title\n\tb)Standby Source\n\tc)ADS Source\n\td)Back Button\n\n" ;
$verfText .= " - The air data source submenu title with the "  ;
$verfText .= "text 'ADS' on line one and 'Source' on line two.\n\n" ;
$verfText .= " - Standby Source(ADS4) validity is valid and the Standby Source menu item is shown as a radio button " ;
$verfText .= "with the label 'STBY' on line one and 'ADS' on line two.\n\n" ;
$verfText .= " - Label 'ADS' on line one and 'Source' on line two in ADS Source momentary submenu button and " ;
$verfText .= "it is displayed in white." ;

#print $verfText;

$verfText =~ s/[\t\n]//g;

print $verfText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.. try this once.

```
"hi\nhow are \t you?".replace(/[\n|\t]/g, "");
```

If not tell me what's wrong.Okay

So you are using verfText variable then in the end write this line

```
verfText = verfText.replace(/[\n|\t]/g, "");
```

Comment: `|` does not mean OR in character classes, it just matches a literal `|`.  As the other responders have shown, `[\n\t]` is all you need.  Also, I notice you're using JavaScript, and you may be right.  The OP tagged this as a Perl question, but his sample code looks more like JavaScript to me.